# Sentinel Logic App Not Taking Output From a Teams Adaptive Card Question

Tags: power-automate, kql, adaptive-cards, azure-sentinel

My sentinel logic app is not taking the output from a button press for a Teams adaptive card.

I have been using Power Automate for a different project, and the Power Automate logic app can parse the output of the adaptive card just fine for dynamic content as shown[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avOKq.png).

However, when I'm attempting something similar with an adaptive card output in Sentinel's Logic Apps, It's not listed as an option as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6vud.png). The two adaptive cards both use buttons to begin an action, but then only the power automate playbook allows the adaptive card output to be used as dynamic content. I am hoping someone here can help me if possible.